# Can I write an app to reboot my android without root if I don't publish to Google Play Store

Tags: android

Title is pretty self explanatory, but for a little more background;

I have an android device sending me data from a remote location that I will not have access to. It appears that the device works most reliably if I reboot it everyday, so I'd like to have a scheduled job that does this task at 4AM everyday.

I have no issues writing an app for this, but as I'm not as familiar with Android, I want to get all the facts I can before diving into the endeavor. I would not be publishing the app to the Google Play store.

- I realize this would be super easy if I had root access but I cannot root the device.
- I see that [I can use PowerManager to perform the reboot](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#reboot%28java.lang.String%29) but it requires REBOOT permission
- I see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#REBOOT) that the reboot permission is "Not for use by third-party applications", does that mean I **cannot** use it, or does it just signify grounds for my app to be booted from the app store?

---

**EDIT:**
It would be sufficient to turn on/off airplane mode but that also requires root.

Comment: simple answer: You cannot do this without root. Either You can set Your app as a system app, and/or You can use the reboot permission but both need root...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say, you can't reboot / turn airplane mode without root.

You can't use the REBOOT permission, AFAIK. Google Play doesn't matter here.

Why you can't root the device? What device is?

Comment: Can't root due to business limitations.. I had read some stuff mentioning signing the apk with the system key, but I think @Opiatefuchs was saying I'd need root to do that as well.

Comment: Try to restablish network connections from the app. If you can't root at all, at least you can try that